# Why am I getting ConnectionRefusedError with Airflow's LocalExecutor?

Tags: python, airflow, freebsd, airflow-scheduler

When trying to start Airflow's scheduler with the command `airflow scheduler`, I'm getting the following error if `executor = LocalExecutor` is in `airflow.cfg`:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/executors/local_executor.py", line 92, in run
    key, command = self.task_queue.get()
  File "<string>", line 2, in get
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 753, in _callmethod
    self._connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 740, in _connect
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 487, in Client
    c = SocketClient(address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 614, in SocketClient
    s.connect(address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

Python: 3.6.13

Airflow: 1.10.15 (installed with its constraints)

OS: FreeBSD 12

Answer (score 0):

This is because on FreeBSD, the TCP socket's default accept queue is very short (128), so if there are many connections to a socket, which the server doesn't `accept()` fast enough, the kernel will send a TCP RST to the excess requests.

Raising the length of the queue helps preventing this:

`sysctl kern.ipc.soacceptqueue=1024`